# Subrings of invariants in divided power algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, divided-powers, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am wondering to what extent the functors "ring of invariants under a group action $G$"
and "divided power envelope with respect to a $G$-stable ideal" commute.

To be precise, let $R$ be a commutative ring (with unit) and $G$ a group acting on $R$ 
by ring automorphisms.  I am happy to assume that $R$ is a noetherian adic ring 
and that $G$ is profinite acting continuously on $R$, but I do not want to assume that $G$ is finite.

Let $S:=R^G$ be the subring of invariants, and suppose given an ideal $I\subseteq R$
which is $G$-stable.  Denote by $J:=I\cap S$ the contraction of $J$ to $S$,
and let $D(R,I)$ and $D(S,J)$ be the divided power envelopes of $R$ with respect to $I$
and $S$ with respect to $J$.  (I should probably also complete these algebras with respect to 
a $G$-stable ideal of $R$ that is contained in the ideal of definition, so the induced
$G$-action on the completed PD algebras is continuous).

Then $G$ acts on $D(R,I)$ and we have $D(S,J)\subseteq D(R,I)^G$.

> Is this inclusion an equality?

Comment: Rather than creating new tags "divided" and "powers" I retagged with existing tags. I hope this question gets an answer.

Comment: I mushed "divided" and "powers" together.

Comment: @S.Carnahan, I thought about doing that, but was unsure if it would really be a good new tag to create. I don't know much about this area, but if this seems like a tag likely to catch on I'm all for creating it.

Comment: The following example, which shows the answer to my question is "no", was explained to me by BCnrd: Let $R:=\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_n][X]$ for $n>1$ and $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity, with $G:=\mu_n$ acting on $R$ via $\zeta\cdot X:=\zeta X$. The PD envelope of $R$ relative to $I:=(x)$ contains the $G$-invariant element $X^n/n!$, whereas the PD envelope of $R^G=\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_n][X^n]$ relative to $I^G=(x^n)$ does not (as can be easily checked by grading everything by degree).

Comment: @B.Cais, if BCnrd doesn't want to post that as an answer for some reason, then I suggest you post it as an answer (in CW mode) and accept it. That way this question won't pop back to the front-page as "unanswered"